# Putting break points or line breaks in the comment section (Python - Django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

**Update 2**

I tried to use `<div class="row">`after looking at the Bootstrap material but the comments still appeared to be rendering in a series of columns and not rows.

[image]

```
<article class="media content-section">
        <!-- comments -->
         <h2>{{ comments.count }} Comments</h2>
        {% for comment in comments %}

          <div class="row">
            <div class="media-body ">
                <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.name }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>

            <p class="article-content">{{ comment.body  }}</p>
          </div>





            {% endfor %}
      </article>
```

**Update**

This is now how my site is rending - 
[image]

It doesn't appear as if the `br` is doing anything.

```
<article class="media content-section">
        <!-- comments -->
         <h2>{{ comments.count }} Comments</h2>
        {% for comment in comments %}

        <div class="media-body ">
            <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.name }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>
        <h3 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
        <p class="article-content">{{ comment.body  }}</p>

        <br><br><br>
        <p>test2 test2</p>
        <br><br><br>
        <p>test2 test2</p>
        <br><br><br>

        {% endfor %}
  </article>
```

**Original Post**

This is how my site is rendering -

[image]

I tried putting `<br>` and `</br>` in a few places and I have not seen any impact. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<article class="media content-section">
        <!-- comments -->
         <h3>{{ comments.count }} Comments</h3>
         <br><br/>
        {% for comment in comments %}

        <div class="media-body ">
            <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.name }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>
        <br><br/>
        <h2 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ comment.body  }}</p>
        <br><br/>

        {% endfor %}
  </article>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not clear

Comment: I want the comments to appear underneath each other. In the above screen shot, the formatting is entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `<br>` tag is a pure HTML construct and what I mean by this it is very low level. It is not enough here, you need to assign appropriate css classes to your data.

I can see that you are using boostrap css framework, judging by class names like "col-md-8". You have some other custom css classes on top of it like "media-content-section".

It is hard to give you advice, because I don't know what those custom classes do. But, bootstrap uses a [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and has a "row" class for new rows. Try that.

You are probably modifying some sample you found and you probably deleted the rest of the comments that were there and put a for loop there. In general your approach is right, just be more careful and attentive if you do this. I would restore those comments and see what's different in your code now.

Answer (score 0):

In short use:

```
&#013;
```

text character for br tag